# Solving the inverse of a matrix under a uniform distribution

Tags: integration, random-matrices, matrix-equations

I am looking to solve the following equation:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}{ g_{11}} & { g_{12}} \\ { g_{21}} & { g_{22}}\end{array}\right)=\int_{a}^{b} \frac{1}{b-a}\left(\begin{array}{cc}{- g_{22}} & { z-u-\tau g_{21}} \\ { z^{*}-u-\tau g_{12}} & {- g_{11}}\end{array}\right)^{-1} \mathrm{d} u$$

Where $\{g_{11},g_{12},g_{21},g_{22}\}\in\mathbb{C}$ are the unknown of my equation. $z^*$ refers to the complex conjugate of $z$. Finally, $u$ $\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\tau$ $\in \mathbb{R}$.

My main issue is that after integration there are $\arctan$'s coming along the way and I do not know how/if analytical solutions can be found. Perhaps there is a trick that could be used and that I do not see?

For some other distributions, this equation is solvable, so I am surprised that a uniform distribution brings me so much obstacles.

Any remark or observation is always appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no escape from the transcendental equation $\tan x=c x$, which has no closed form solution in $x$.